# Formato fecha php

Tags: php, date

Tengo esta fecha en php:

```
31082016
```

Y quiero pasarla a este formato:

```
dd-mm-yyyy
```

Tengo el siguiente código, pero me da error:

```
echo "<br/><hr/>" . $fechaIn . "<hr/><br/>";
echo "<br/><hr/>" . date('d-m-Y', $fechaIn) . "<hr/><br/>";
```

Y me muestra lo siguiente:

```html
<br/>
<hr/>31082016<hr/>
<br/>
<br/>
<hr/>26-12-1970<hr/>
<br/>
```

Cual puede ser el problema??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tienes otra opción que sería separar cada elemento y tratarlo después.

Manteniendo el patrón que has iniciado;

```
$fechaIn = '31082016';

$y = substr( $fechaIn, 4, 4 );
$m = substr( $fechaIn, 2, 2 );
$d = substr( $fechaIn, 0, 2 );

echo "<br/><hr/>" . $fechaIn . "<hr/><br/>";
echo "<br/><hr/>" . date( 'd-m-Y', mktime( 0, 0, 0, $m, $d, $y ) ) . "<hr/><br/>";
```

Answer (score 7):

La función `date()` toma como parámetro un número que es un **timestamp** (es decir la cantidad de segundos que pasaron desde el 01/01/1970. Por eso te devuelve esa fecha.

#### Modificar el string directamente

Lo que tenés es un `string` que está formado como `ddmmaaaa` (día-mes-año). Lo único que necesitás para darle el formato que buscás en agregar los guiones para separarlos.

Usamos [**`substr_replace()`**](http://php.net/manual/es/function.substr-replace.php) para agregar un guión en la posición 2 y en la posición 4:

```php
echo substr_replace(substr_replace($fechaIn, '-', 4, 0), '-', 2, 0);
```

---

#### Convertir un string en fecha

Si quisieras convertir el string en formato de fecha primero, la mejor opción es usar [DateTime::createFromFormat()](http://php.net/manual/es/datetime.createfromformat.php):

```php
$fechaIn = '31082016';

//Convertir un string a fecha
$fechaDateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('dmY', $fechaIn);

//Imprimir la fecha en el formato deseado
echo $fechaDateTime->format('d-m-Y');
```

**Resultado**

```
31-08-2016
```

Comment: Quizá es más fácil transformar el `string` a un `timestamp`? =P

Comment: Una opción interesante @Mariano

Answer (score 3):

Tres ejemplos en el formato que indicas:

**Ejemplo 1**

```
<?php
$source = '2012-07-31';
$date = new DateTime($source);
echo $date->format('d.m.Y'); // 31.07.2012
echo $date->format('d-m-Y'); // 31-07-2012
?>
```

**Ejemplo 2**

```
date("d/m/Y", strtotime($str));
```

**Ejemplo 3**

```
$var = '20/04/2012';
$date = str_replace('/', '-', $var);
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date));
```

> Te recomiendo observar formatos y más funciones [Aquí](http://php.net/manual/es/datetime.format.php) y [Aquí](http://php.net/manual/es/function.date.php)